# Cancel completion, but only completion, in zsh

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, signals

When a completion function takes a long time, [I can interrupt it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39404/cancel-zsh-tab-completion) by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (terminal interrupt key, sends SIGINT) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (bound to `send-break`). I am then left with the uncompleted word.

However, if I happen to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> just as the completion function finishes, my key press may cancel the command line and give me a fresh prompt instead of cancelling the completion.

How can I set up zsh so that a certain key will cancel an ongoing completion but do nothing if no completion function is active?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution that sets up a SIGINT handler that makes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> only interrupt when completion is active.

```
# A completer widget that sets a flag for the duration of
# the completion so the SIGINT handler knows whether completion
# is active. It would be better if we could check some internal
# zsh parameter to determine if completion is running, but as 
# far as I'm aware that isn't possible.
function interruptible-expand-or-complete {
    COMPLETION_ACTIVE=1

    # Bonus feature: automatically interrupt completion
    # after a three second timeout.
    # ( sleep 3; kill -INT $$ ) &!

    zle expand-or-complete

    COMPLETION_ACTIVE=0
}

# Bind our completer widget to tab.
zle -N interruptible-expand-or-complete
bindkey '^I' interruptible-expand-or-complete

# Interrupt only if completion is active.
function TRAPINT {
    if [[ $COMPLETION_ACTIVE == 1 ]]; then
        COMPLETION_ACTIVE=0
        zle -M "Completion canceled."            

        # Returning non-zero tells zsh to handle SIGINT,
        # which will interrupt the completion function. 
        return 1
    else
        # Returning zero tells zsh that we handled SIGINT;
        # don't interrupt whatever is currently running.
        return 0
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an acceptable solution or not, but sending a SIGSTOP (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) seems to have the desired effect, with the added benefit that you can start up the autocomplete again if you send a SIGSTART (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>) before typing anything else. I'm not an expert on job control though, so this may leave some additional clutter related to the stopped job.

Comment: Ctrl+S and Ctrl+Q are flow control commands. They only affect output to the terminal, which is irrelevant here. Predictably, Ctrl+S has no effect during completion (zsh disables the terminal setting anyway, it grabs the key combination). Pressing Ctrl+Z (which sends SIGTOP) has no effect either.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't entirely sure what was going on in the background. All I saw was that I got control of the terminal back.